# Event handler in jquery flot legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, flot

I'm plotting an arbitrary number of data sets with plot jquery. The legend of the plot is dynamically generated, because I have no information about how many datasets will be a priori. 
What I want is that whenever the user click the label of one of the series, its graph gets highlighted. I found that reordering the datasets' array will do the job. 
The problem is when the user clicks the legend.
My code for the legend is:

```
     legend: {
                noColumns: 0,

                labelFormatter: function(label, series){
                    var lab = '<a href="#" style="color:black" id="'+label.split('/')[1]+'">' + label.split('/')[0] + '</a>';
                    return lab;
                },
                backgroundColor: "#000",
                backgroundOpacity: 0.9,
                labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000",
                position: "nw"
            },
```

I've tried to set a handler inside the labelFormatter function, but this doesn't work. Also I've tried to set a class for each label and access them outside the outer function, but it doesn't work either. In short, I don't know how to access to the label, nor when or where to put the event handler. Could you help me please?

Comment: Is it practical for you to use a custom container and use delegation to bind events for that? Or are you constrained to the "position" option?

Comment: I can't use a custom container

Answer (score 3):

I think what you have is close. What I would suggest is to put a class on the anchor tag you are returning from the label formatter. Something like this:

```
labelFormatter: function(label, series){
    var lab = '<a href="#" class="legendButton" style="color:black" id="'+label.split('/')[1]+'">' + label.split('/')[0] + '</a>';
    return lab;
}
```

Then, using delegation (jQuery's "on") you can get events on the legend if you have access to the chart's placeholder. For example:

```
$('#chartPlaceholderId').on('click', '.legendButton', function () {
    // do stuff
});
```

Alternatively, you might be able to use your browser's element inspector to see if there are any default classes that can be used to bind events to the legend. Either way, you will probably have to use delegation so any legend that is rendered after the event binding is created will still register the events.